# Unexepected behavior from multiple bitwise shifts on the same line

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I get a different result depending on if I combine multiple bitwise shifts on one line or put them on separate lines.

```
unsigned char a = 73;
a = (a << 6) >> 2;
printf("%d\n", a);
```

prints 144 when I expect 16

```
unsigned char a = 73;
a = a << 6;
a = a >> 2;
printf("%d\n", a);
```

prints the expected result of 16

when I shift left 6, then right 1 on one line, it prints the expected result of 32, so it
looks like the 2nd shift right is shifting in a 1 instead of a 0, but why?

Also

```
a = (unsigned char) (a << 6 ) >> 2;
```

produces the expected result (16).

Is the first left shift returning a signed char instead of an unsigned char, and if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the result of the first shift is signed.  `signed int` specifically.  Check out the rules for the "integer promotions" in the C spec:

> If an **`int`** can represent all values of the original type ... the value is converted to an **`int`**...

So, since your `int` - usually a range of [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup>) - can represent all the values of `unsigned char` - usually [0, 255] - it's converted to `int`, and the `<<` and `>>` take place on the resulting values.