# Unexpected result after chaining bit-shift operators in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

I can't figure out why chaining bit-shift operations is not returning the same  result as not chaining them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bit_manip_func(unsigned char byte)
{
    unsigned char chain = (((byte >> 3) << 7) >> 3);
    printf("%d\n", chain); //this prints 144

    unsigned char o1 = byte >> 3;
    unsigned char o2 = o1 << 7;
    unsigned char o3 = o2 >> 3;
    printf("%d\n", o3); //this prints 16 as expected
}

int main()
{
    //expecting both printf's to print
    //the same value (16).
    bit_manip_func(73);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting both `printf` calls to print out 16 since 73 in binary is 0100 1001. After applying `byte >> 3` I should get 0000 1001, after `(byte >> 3) << 7` the result should be 1000 0000, and after `(((byte >> 3) << 7) >> 3)` the result should be 0001 0000, which of course is 16. What's actually happening?

Comment: [Integer promotion](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/), every second  time a question like this is asked.

Comment: maybe, but I had no idea it had anything to do with integer promotion.

Comment: It's an important rule to remember: `int` is a special type in C, and all smaller types get promoted to `int` during calculations. Which is also why source code compiled for a 16-bit architecture (where `int` is 16 bits wide) will behave differently when compiled for 32-bits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does combining two shifts of a uint8\_t produce a different result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702091/why-does-combining-two-shifts-of-a-uint8-t-produce-a-different-result)

Comment: [Unexepected behavior from multiple bitwise shifts on the same line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25393058/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operators >> and << perform integer promotions on their operands. Thus the type unsigned char is promoted to int, when used with either operator.

In the following line, the variable byte is promoted to type int, and then all three operations are performed on this type:

```
unsigned char chain = (((byte >> 3) << 7) >> 3);
```

The left most bit set to one is thus preserved:

```
01001001 => 01001 => 010010000000 => 010010000 
 ^           ^        ^               ^
```

In the following code, the variables are promoted to type int, but after each operation, the result, which has the type int, is assigned to an unsigned char and thus wraps (most significant bits are removed),
since the range of unsigned char is [ 0 , 2^8-1 ] on your platform.

```
unsigned char o1 = byte >> 3;
unsigned char o2 = o1 << 7;
unsigned char o3 = o2 >> 3;
```

This means that the left most bit set to one is not preserved:

```
01001001 => 01001 => 10000000 => 000010000
 ^           ^
```

Comment: this explanation is pretty awesome

Comment: @cuvidk Thank you, I try.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
unsigned char chain = (((byte >> 3) << 7) >> 3);
```

`((byte >> 3) << 7)` is promoted to an `int`, then it performs `>> 3` over the `int`

Wrapped to an `unsigned char` (mod 256) you get `((73 >> 3) << 7) >> 3) % 256` = `144`

Use a cast:

```
unsigned char chain = ((unsigned char)((byte >> 3) << 7) >> 3);
```

Comment: In a general case, it would be better to cast the input `byte` to `unsigned int`, then explicitly cast the final result to `unsigned char`. Intermediate cast to `unsigned char` only makes sense when possible loss of most significant bits is intentional, as it will again get promoted to `int`. Splitting the operations would be clearer. Also, the result of right shifting a negative integer value is implementation defined, so bit shift operations should always be done on unsigned integer types of rank `unsigned int` _or higher_. Extra points for fixed width `<stdint.h>` types.

Comment: You mean `(unsigned char)((((unsigned int)byte >> 3) << 7) >> 3))`?, that's not the desired output (16), is still 144

Comment: No, didn't mean that for the specific case where the loss of data _is_ intended. Hence "in a general case", so as additional information only. Your answer already covers this specific situation.